# Harris corner detector detects diagonal edges as corners

Tags: computer-vision, glsl, corner-detection

I'm trying to implement a Harris corner detector in WebGL / GLSL (the first part in a larger CV algorithm). As far as I can see, my Gaussian and Sobel operators work as intended (i.e. it's a blur, and Sobel gives me the derivative of the intensity of my image).

The problem I'm having is that the Harris corner detector response is too high for diagonal edges – according to the detector, any diagonal edge is all corners. This is incorrect, of course, but I am not sure why. No matter how I tweak the response formula, it seems to have this problem.

Here is my shader code:

```
precision mediump float;

// the texture I am trying to detect the corners in
// (fed from a live video source)
uniform sampler2D sampler2d;

// the Gaussian / Sobel kernels are precalculated and passed as textures
uniform sampler2D gaussian_x;
uniform sampler2D gaussian_y;

// stdev for the Gaussian
#define sigma (3.0)
#define sigma_ceil (3.0)

// pixel_w and pixel_h represent the size of pixels in tex coords
#define pixel_w (1.0 / 960.0)
#define pixel_h (1.0 / 540.0)

const float offset_start = -(sigma_ceil * 3.0);
const float offset_end   = ((sigma_ceil * 3.0) + .5);
const float pixel_gauss  = 1.0 / (sigma_ceil * 2.0 + 1.0);

varying vec4 fPosition;
varying vec2 fTexCoord;

void main(){
  vec2 texCoord = vec2(fTexCoord.s, fTexCoord.t);

  vec3 total_x = vec3(0, 0, 0);
  vec3 total_y = vec3(0, 0, 0);

  for (float x = offset_start; x < offset_end; x += 1.0){
    for (float y = offset_start; y < offset_end; y += 1.0){
      total_x += texture2D(sampler2d, vec2(texCoord.s + x * pixel_w, texCoord.y + y * pixel_h)).rgb
        * ((texture2D(gaussian_x, vec2((x - offset_start) * pixel_gauss, (y - offset_start) * pixel_gauss)).rgb
           - vec3(0.5)) * .1)
        * 255.0
        ;
      total_y += texture2D(sampler2d, vec2(texCoord.s + x * pixel_w, texCoord.y + y * pixel_h)).rgb
        * ((texture2D(gaussian_y, vec2((x - offset_start) * pixel_gauss, (y - offset_start) * pixel_gauss)).rgb
           - vec3(0.5)) * .1)
        * 255.0
        ;
    }
  }

  float total_xf = (total_x.r + total_x.g + total_x.b) / 3.0;
  float total_yf = (total_y.r + total_y.g + total_y.b) / 3.0;

  float a = (total_xf * total_xf); // Ix2
  float b = (total_yf * total_yf); // Iy2
  float c = (total_xf * total_yf); // Ixy
  float det = (a * b) - c;
  float trc = a + b;

  float res = det - 0.04 * (trc * trc);

  res += .5; // to see when it goes negative

  gl_FragColor = vec4(res, res, res, 1);
}
```

After this I would do non-maximum suppression, and thresholding, but the result of this step already seems wrong. The two gaussian samplers sample from textures like this:

[image: Gaussian / Sobel kernels]

These are precalculated and are the reason I subtract .5 from each pixel (because the grey pixels actually represent a 0 weight). The .1 and 255 factors make the image visible for me, I've tried many different values, but I don't think they are the issue.

I've also tried using the `res = det / trc` approximation, but the results seem worse. The issue persists. Using a standard checkerboard pattern, like this one:

[image: Calibration pattern]

This is what the result is when I show it to the camera horizontally:

[image: Result (horizontal)]

I'm not sure what is happening with the horizontal edges, but the vertical edges are black (as expected), and the corners show very white pixels, which produce the expected result when thresholded. However, when I turn the pattern diagonally:

[image]

All the edges are now white. I've been tweaking a lot with various values, used a higher stdev for the Gaussians, etc, but nothing seems to produce the expected result. Is it simply that the Harris detector detects diagonal edges as corners? I doubt that, seeing some other implementations.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

(Also, before you suggest openCV … This is running in WebGL, and I want to / should implement this algorithm myself.)

Comment: OTOH, could it be that you are saturating everywhere? What happens if the "visualization gain" is, say, 10 instead of 255?

Comment: @FrancescoCallari If I do that, the output is much fainter, … So after multiplying it (the `res` variable) to see what it does, I can see it still has a very high response for any diagonal edge. Higher than the response for corners in a horizontal test. I changed it to 10, then to 1, had to multiply res by 10000 to see anything. If I can spot any difference it is that with a lower gain the diagonal edges now show up as white AND black (i.e. positive and negative) depending on the orientation? Originally the edges were all clearly white, some of them had a black outline though.